# Eigen vectors not initialized when cross-compiled for ARM

Tags: gcc, arm, cross-compiling, eigen, eigen3

I'm using Eigen3 on a cross compiled program using the arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ (gcc version 4.8 from Linaro). The target platform is a duovero from gumstix using the Poky distribution - ARMv7. When I run the program with the Eigen code I get really strange values on the Eigen objects (see the output example at the end of this post).

I've tried to turn off vectorization, I've played with all these flags

```
-marm 
-mcpu=cortex-a7
-mfpu=neon 
-mfloat-abi=hard
```

but always get the same behavior. If I compile the same code on the duovero it works ok (vectors are properly initialized) but not when I cross-compile. I've even cross-compiled from different hosts (windows7 and ubuntu 14.04).

Any idea why this is happening?

This is my simple program (updated from comments)

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#include <stdio.h>

#include <Eigen/Eigen>
#include <Eigen/Dense>
using namespace Eigen;

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello World!" << endl;
    int j =3;
    cout << j << endl << endl; // ok

    float k =4.2;
    cout << k << endl << endl; // not ok

    printf("%f\n\n", k ); // ok

    Vector3d test1;
    test1 << 1.2, 2.3, 3.4;
    cout << test1 << endl << endl; // not ok

    printf("%f\n\n", test1(0) ); // ok

    Vector3d test2(1,2,3);
    cout << test2 << endl; // not ok
    cout << test2(1) << endl << endl; // not ok

    printf("%f\n\n", test2(0) ); // ok

    cout << 0.5f << endl; // not ok
    printf("%f\n\n", 0.5f ); // ok

    return 0;
}
```

This is the output I get (updated)

```
Hello World!
3

0

4.200000

-1.24694e-06
-1.24695e-06
-1.24695e-06

1.200000

-1.24692e-06
-1.24692e-06
-1.24693e-06
3.8852e+68

1.000000

0
0.500000
```

Edit
When I add the flag: -mfloat-abi=soft I get this error

```
arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ -c -mfloat-abi=soft -g -Wall -W -fPIE  -IC:\tmp\testingEigen -I. -IC:\COSMOS\source\thirdparty\arm\eigen3 -IC:\Qt\5.4\mingw491_32\mkspecs\linux-arm-gnueabihf-g++ -o main.obj C:\tmp\testingEigen\main.cpp
arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++  -o testingEigen main.obj    
c:/program files (x86)/linaro/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-4.8-2014.01/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.8.3/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld.exe: error: testingEigen uses VFP register arguments, main.obj does not
makefile:79: recipe for target 'testingEigen' failed
c:/program files (x86)/linaro/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-4.8-2014.01/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.8.3/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld.exe: failed to merge target specific data of file main.obj
```

**update:**
I tried what Notlikethat suggested. Tested the libraries (ex. readelf -h /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.18) and found that the current built is definitively soft-float ABI.

When I link statically my the code works well (even if cross compiler is for hard float, this works because the hardware actually has an FPU even if the image is configured for soft fp). The next thing I did was to find a cross compiler that is able to do do softfp, and it also worked when I added the flag. I downloaded it from https://launchpad.net/linaro-toolchain-binaries/+milestone/2012.04.

I guess my next step is to compile a poky image for the duovero that can do hard float. Has anyone done this?

**final update:** 
I've actually just compiled the latest poky image from yocto (poky 1.7) for the duovero using these instructions https://github.com/gumstix/yocto-manifest

and realised that this build uses hard fp. Now my cross compiler (arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++) and the target have the same floating point configuration and my code with Eigen and everything else is working perfectly! Happy! :)

Comment: This certainly smells like a float ABI issue (I wouldn't even rule out some dodgy "works fine on x86" casting in the library code) - in "played with these flags", do you mean to say you've explicitly tried `-mfloat-abi=soft`? It's quite likely that the cross-compilers may be configured with different defaults from the native one, so you can't necessarily expect the _absence_ of an option to imply consistent behaviour.

Comment: When I add -mfloat-abi=soft I get this error: ld.exe: error: testingEigen uses VFP register arguments, main.obj does not (I've edited the original question and added the full output I get from the compiler). At this moment my cross compiler seems to be configured only for hard float. Does Eigen require soft-float to work?

Comment: Add `-mfloat-abi=soft` to linker flags in addition to compiler flags.

Comment: Hmm, does something as simple as `cout << 0.5f << endl;` still behave the same way?

Comment: @TurboJ,if I only add -mfloat-abi=soft to the linker flags (not to the compiler flags) it compiles ok but if I keep it for the compiler flag I get the same problem I mentioned about the VFP register arguments. I'm starting to think that the problem is because the cross compiler is only for hard floating point. Any suggestions for a cross compiler for ARM with soft or softfp that works on Windows?

Comment: @Notlikethat, wow! if I add `cout << 0.5f << endl;` as you suggested it won't work, but if I use`printf("%f\n\n", 0.5f );` it works. I'm getting confused about this behavior. Does this have to do with the ABI? (I've updated the code above so you can see other examples working/not working)

Comment: Heh, `printf` is extra-confusing since it's a variadic function, so gets its arguments passed slightly differently anyway ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem would seem to be that you have a soft-float libstdc++ (and friends) on the device.

Consider an innocuous-looking function like `std::ostream::operator<<(float)` - when you cross-compile with the hard-float toolchain, you generate code which will pass the float to the function in an FPU register. The static linker knows enough to double-check that this matches the libraries it's linking against (the hard-float ones bundled with the cross-toolchain itself). Then you take that binary and run it on the device...

The dynamic linker, being less clever, is just going to make sure that whatever libstdc++ it finds provides the symbols the program is asking for. It finds one of a similar-enough version which fits that bill, so all seems good. Except now you've got the situation where your code is passing float arguments to library functions in FPU registers, but the library functions (being soft-float) are expecting their float arguments in general-purpose registers, so they find uninitialised junk.

The best thing to do is to avoid the "link against one library, run against another" mismatch entirely, for which there are 3 reasonable options, in roughly decreasing order of severity:

1. Link statically when you cross-compile.
2. Put the cross-toolchain's hard-float libraries somewhere on the device's filesystem where you cross-compiled programs can find them (possibly resorting to LD_LIBRARY_PATH) - obviously you can't simply replace the existing libraries or you'd get the inverse ABI mismatch for the rest of your installed programs.
3. Copy the system libraries off the device onto your host machine, so you can point the cross-linker at them instead of its bundled libraries, and cross-compile with `--mfloat-abi=soft`.

I'd normally suggest option 3 as the general case, however hard-float does have somewhat of a performance benefit so for floating-point-intensive code, so it may well be worth the bit of effort to get it to work.

Note that whilst some hard-float (i.e. "arm-linux-gnueabi**hf**-") cross-toolchains also include soft-float libraries via multilib, others (like the Linaro ones I use) either don't, or only enable them for specific combinations of options representing ancient targets, which you probably don't want. If you *did* have a suitable multilib toolchain, that's what @TurboJ's suggestion in the comments is about - using `arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc` as the link command (*not* `arm-linux-gnueabihf-ld`) with `--mfloat-abi=soft` specified would tell it to link against the soft-float versions of its libraries if it supports that.