# How to isolate a fault on arm device?

Tags: c++, arm, rapidjson

I am using rapidjson on an Arm device and get strange behaviour, when running this code.

```
    #include <document.h>
    using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const char json []="[{\"Type\":\"float\",\"val_param\" : 12.025 }]";

    rapidjson::Document d;

    if( d.Parse<0>( json ).HasParseError() ) {
     //ErrorCase
    }else{
        rapidjson:: Value& val_param    = d[0]["val_param"];
        double tmp_double1  = val_param.GetDouble(); 
        cout << tmp_double1 <<endl; // -9.2559641157289301e+61 instead of 12.025
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Before down voting this question. What else information do you need? I really don't know how to isolate this fault. If it occurs because of the embedded device, or rapidjson. And how to solve it.

========================== UPDATE ========================================

What is the device? http://www.keith-koep.com/de/produkte/produkte-trizeps/trizeps-iv-m-eigenschaften/

Does it have a hardware FPU? It is ARMv5 so I don't think so.

What compiler and libraries are you using (version numbers/specific builds)?
What options are you passing to the compiler and linker?

```
arm-linux-gnueabi-g++ -march=armv5te -marm -mthumb-interwork --sysroot=/usr/local/oecore-x86_64/sysroots/armv5te-linux-gnueabi
```

Comment: It supposed to be `d`.

Comment: DOOM.....................

Comment: Don't you have a debugger to operate on your device?

Comment: Indexing an array by a string? O.o The [c] tag is clearly out of place here... Anyway, this smells like a floating-point ABI issue, so to start with: What is the device? Does it have a hardware FPU? What compiler and libraries are you using (version numbers/specific builds)? What options are you passing to the compiler and linker? How are their defaults configured for the options you're _not_ passing?

Comment: Have you tried this on a different device?

Comment: Sure, I use gdb for remote debugging. But all I see is `GetDouble()` is not working.

Comment: @Mohamad Elghawi The code works on Ubuntu perfect!

Comment: @user5473325 That answers your question as to whether this issue is to do with your particular device or rapidjson.

Comment: [Similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30133534/3156750); you could well have the same [root cause](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31500570/3156750) here. When you say "`GetDouble()` is not working" do you mean specifically that you see an unexpected value returned and assigned to `tmp_double1`, _before_ the output call? Again; compiler and linker options? Does linking statically make any difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like it might be an undefined-behaviour-type bug in RapidJSON.

Since you're targeting ARMv5, you're probably using a software floating-point library using the legacy ARM FPA format (as opposed to the later VFP, which uses IEEE754 format). Crucially, the FPA stores things in a weird middle-endian format, where 64-bit doubles are stored as two little-endian words, but most-significant word first.

(Yes, big-endian ARM is a whole other complicated issue, but I'm deliberately ignoring it here since I don't see an `armeb-*` triplet or the `-mbig-endian` option anywhere)

Consider 12.025 as an IEEE754 double:

```
64-bit value:             0x40280ccccccccccd.
little-endian byte order: cd cc cc cc cc 0c 28 40
as little-endian words:   0xcccccccd 0x40280ccc
```

Now in FPA format that would be:

```
as little-endian words:   0x40280ccc 0xcccccccd
byte order:               cc 0c 28 40 cd cc cc cc
```

Trying to interpret that as a pure little-endian 64-bit value yields 0xcccccccd40280ccc, which just so happens to be the IEEE754 representation of -9.255965e+61. Fancy that!

---

From a quick look around the code, it may strictly be more of an incompatibility than a bug, since RapidJSON does seem to explicitly assume IEEE754 format for floating-point values. To its credit, even though [the parsing code](https://github.com/miloyip/rapidjson/blob/master/include/rapidjson/internal/strtod.h) looks pretty hairy, I do see [unions](https://github.com/miloyip/rapidjson/blob/master/include/rapidjson/internal/ieee754.h#L68) rather than type-punning pointers. However, even if it's not relying on *undefined* behaviour, it's still relying on *implementation-defined* behaviour (the format of floating-point types), and unfortunately this compiler's implementation doesn't match that expectation.

Comment: Thank you very much for the comprehensive answer. So I should rather use an other json-parser I guess. Or is there still a chance to get it work?